# Run a shortcut under windows

Tags: python, windows

The following doesn't work, because it doesn't wait until the process is finished:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('start /WAIT /B MOZILL~1.LNK', shell=True)
p.wait()
```

Any idea how to run a shortcut and wait that the subprocess returns ?

**Edit:** originally I was trying this without the **shell** option in my post, which caused Popen to fail. In effect, `start` is not an executable but a shell command. This was fixed thanks to Jim.

Comment: What do you want to do, in terms of "control over the launched process"?

Comment: subprocess return an object. os.system just return a code. This is what I mean by having better control on the executed program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to invoke a shell to get the subprocess option to work:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('start /B MOZILL~1.LNK', shell=True)
p.wait()
```

This however will still exit immediately (see @R. Bemrose).

If `p.pid` contains the correct pid (I'm not sure on windows), then you could use [`os.waitpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid) to wait for the program to exit. Otherwise you may need to use some win32 com magic.

Comment: This solved partially the problem. Now the subprocess.Popen command works. But still p.wait() returns as soon as the process was launched.

Comment: p.pid is correct, but os.waitpid won't work. I guess you're right, I need to go for win32process module, and run the process through this interface. I am not done yet, but I get closer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

cmd.exe is terminating as soon as start launches the program.  This behavior is documented (in start /? ):

> If Command Extensions are enabled,
>   external command invocation through
>   the command line or the START command
>   changes as follows:

...

> When executing an application that is
>   a 32-bit GUI application, CMD.EXE
>   does not wait for the application to terminate before returning to
>   the command prompt.  This new behavior does NOT occur if executing
>   within a command script.

How this is affected by the /wait flag, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am simply adding on Jim's reply, with a small trick.
What about using 'WAIT' option for start?

```
p = subprocess.Popen('start /B MOZILL~1.LNK /WAIT', shell=True)
p.wait()
```

This should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything