# How to launch a Window's shortcut using Python

Tags: python, window

I want to launch a shortcut named `blender.ink` located at `"D://games//blender.ink"`. I have tryed using:-

```
os.startfile ("D://games//blender.ink")
```

But it failed, it only launches exe files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a shortcut under windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349653/run-a-shortcut-under-windows)

Comment: Does `blender.ink` launch correctly if you double click on it from Windows Explorer? i.e. Does it have the correct association?

Comment: Please note, Windows shortcuts have a `.lnk` extension, not .`ink`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Python [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=startfile#os.startfile) function should work fine, but you need to specify a `.lnk` extension to be a valid Windows shortcut file:

```
import os

os.startfile (r"D:\games\blender.lnk")
```

If you need to wait for the application to complete before continuing, then a different approach would be needed as follows:

```
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
import win32event

se_ret = shell.ShellExecuteEx(fMask=0x140, lpFile=r"D:\games\blender.lnk", nShow=1)
win32event.WaitForSingleObject(se_ret['hProcess'], -1)
```