# How to open OBS Studio using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, obs-studio

I am trying to figure out how to open OBS Studio using a python script. I have used either of the two little code snippets below, but none work when ran separately. However, when ran together, my OBS Studio opens,  however I am met with the following error:

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\\OBS_Studio")

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\\OBS_Studio")
```

[image]

So my question is, am I doing something incorrectly because I don't know if I add more to the script, if that error message will kill the process, unless I add some sort of error-handling code. However, I don't think that will be necessary as this message is almost assuredly due to user error on my part. I have added an image of my OBS Studio's location as well for reference.
[image]

Additionally, just incase the issue is due to me referencing the shortcut, here is a screenshot of the .exe's file path. And when I convert the two snippets of code to reference the .exe path, the same error pops up, however OBS Studio doesn't open at all.

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe")
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe")
```

[image]

Comment: You're only using single slashes in your last snippet

Comment: In your first example, you're trying to invoke a Windows shortcut, but you've left off the required file extension (`.lnk`) for some reason. Duplicate of [How to launch a Window's shortcut using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737206/how-to-launch-a-windows-shortcut-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

In the example with the absolute path to the exe, make sure you escape the backslashes by using \. Your code should look like this:

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\\Program Files\\obs-studio\\bin\\64bit\\obs64.exe")
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("C:\\Program Files\\obs-studio\\bin\\64bit\\obs64.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the string of the open file, the address string information similar to `c:\user\desktop` will inevitably be involved, which conflicts with the escape function in Python string. For example, `\n` means newline.

We can use `r"c:\user\desktop"` or `c:\\user\\desktop` to avoid Python escaping strings.