# Unable to launch windows shortcut

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to launch a windows with python. I've tried NUMEROUS approaches with os.system, subprocess.call, os.startfile etc. but I'm always getting an error saying that the path does not exist.

I know that the path is correct because  I've tried running the following command in CMD.EXE:

```
start D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk
```

Here is some of the stuff I've tried without success:

```
os.startfile(r"D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk")
os.startfile("D:\\johan\\programmering\\Scripts\\shortcuts\\HWMonitor.lnk")
subprocess.call("D:\\johan\\programmering\\Scripts\\shortcuts\\HWMonitor.lnk")
subprocess.call(r"D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk")
subprocess.Popen(r"D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk")
subprocess.Popen(r"D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk", shell=True)
os.system(r"start D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk")

p= subprocess.Popen(r"start D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk", shell=True)
p.wait()

import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(r"D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk")
subprocess.call(shortcut.Targetpath)
```

**DISCLAIMER** I know that there are similar questions asked on SO, but none of them have helped me. So before you start crying "duplicate!" please know that I've tried the solutions with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a shortcut under windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349653/run-a-shortcut-under-windows)

Comment: @Aaron already tried that.

Comment: @Aaron I've added my attempt to the question now. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `os.startfile` should work, as well as `subprocess.Popen` and friends with `shell=True` -- because in both cases you eventually call `ShellExecute[Ex]`, the shell API that understands how to open .lnk files. `CreateProcess` (as called by `Popen`) doesn't know anything about .lnk shortcuts, so if you need to use one with `Popen` without `shell=True` (and only in that case), then you have to extract the target and working directory from the shortcut using the shell COM interface.

Comment: @eryksun os.listdir works fine

Comment: @eryksun os.path.exists returns false

Comment: Is "HW‌​Monitor.lnk" in the list that's returned by `os.listdir(r'D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts')`?

Comment: @eryksun Yes, it is in the list

Comment: @eryksun new error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:\\johan\\programmering\\Scripts\\shortcuts\\HW\u200c\u200bMonit\u200c\u200bor.lnk'`

Comment: same error as before

Comment: I don't know what's injecting the invisible characters. Try `p = r'D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts';` `os.stat(os.path.join(p, 'HWMonitor.lnk'))`.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Should I print the result of os.stat? or what should I do with it?

Comment: If there's no error, then accessing the .lnk file itself isn't the problem. What are the target and working directory set as in the shortcut properties?

Comment: target: "D:\Program Files\CPUID\HWMonitor\HWMonitor.exe", start in: "D:\Program Files\CPUID\HWMonitor"

Comment: "D:\Program Files"? That's unusual. Does that directory exist? And the HWMonitor.exe target?

Comment: yes to both your questions

Comment: In the comments below you say the target is "C:\Program Files (x86)\CPUID\HWMonitor\HWMonitor.exe", but here you say it's  "D:\Program Files" instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)".

Comment: yeah, you're right :S that's strange

Comment: Find HWMonitor.exe in Explorer; create a new shortcut on your desktop; and try running that shortcut instead.

Comment: same error as allways. Unable to find the file

Comment: Try running the executable directly via `subprocess.call`, via both the C: and D: drive paths, with and without `shell=True`. For example, `subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\CPUID\HWMonitor\HWMonitor.exe'])`.

Comment: FINALLY! subprocess.call with the D:\ path works! Still a bit annoyed that I can't open the shortcut, but I'll manage. Thanks alot for your help @eryksun. If you post it as an answer I'll mark you as correct =)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python), you could resolve your link path, then call the resolved path

```
import sys
import win32com.client,win32api

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(r"D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk")
long_path = shortcut.Targetpath
```

but `long_path` may be a strange Windows path with a lot of junk in it, so if

```
subprocess.call([long_path])
```

doesn't work, you can resolve the long path in a short path (8.3 names):

```
short_path=win32api.GetShortPathName(long_path)
```

now do:

```
subprocess.call([short_path])
```

Comment: Having some troubles installing the module, I'll come back to this answer once I've managed to get the module working.

Comment: Ok! so I've managed to get the win32com.client to work and I'm using your exact answer, but I'm still getting `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: ok, can you print `shortcut.Targetpath` ? are you sure your link points to a valid file?, also check my edit

Comment: I can't print shortcut.Targetpath (same error), I've tried with your updated answer (same error) and as I said in the question, it works if I just run `start D:\johan\programmering\Scripts\shortcuts\HWMonitor.lnk` in CMD.EXE, so yes. The path should be correct

Comment: same error when you print?? which error? `print` should work OK

Comment: oups, my bad! Yes, the print works. It prints `C:\Program Files (x86)\CPUID\HWMonitor\HWMonitor.exe` which is where the shortcut points.

Comment: then with my edit it'll work: `subprocess.call([shortcut.Targetpath])` (note the square brackets). and if it doesn't I have another idea.

Comment: It doesn't. I've tried with the square brackets and I'm still getting the "fileNotFound" error.